# Linked list reverse without using the loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I was asked by one of my senior executives that is it possible to reverse an singly linked list without using an loop? If yes, how? His smile seemed to tell me that it is possible but I could not think of anything. Anyone thought about this earlier?

Comment: do you mean that we can do it faster than O(n)? or you mean to say that we can do it with recursion?

Comment: or you can also do it using goto

Comment: @PetarPetrovic, Goto seems interesting. Tell me more.

Comment: I did not think about the detail, but it should be possible to implement loop/recursion using goto.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to reverse a double-linked list in **O(1)** by swapping it's `head` and `tail` pointers, and (depending on the implementation) setting some kind of a flag that will tell that the list should be now iterated backwards (i.e. following the `back` pointers to iterate forward, and following the `next` pointers to iterate backward).

As for a single-linked list, I believe it's impossible to reverse it faster than **O(n)**.

Answer (score 2):

An approach in recursion

```
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node** _reverse(struct node* n)
{
    if (NULL != n->next)
        *_reverse(n->next) = n;
    return &(n->next);
}

// this is the entry
void reverse(struct node* head)
{
    *_reverse(head) = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this code will work?  Mentally trying it with three element list A, B, C and getting *(&nullptr) = B.

Comment: @AMA Just because `c->next == nullptr` does not mean that `*(&c->next)` is the same as `*(&nullptr)`. `c->next` has its address.

Comment: aha! That's elegant. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

In STL there is rbegin() and rend() iterators for traversing collections in reverse order. But it will not work for single linked list.